# how to create limited quantity NFT

Tags: solidity, nft, smart-contract-wallets

I want to create 50 pieces of the same artwork as NFT(for learning purposes).
I want multiple wallets to own one or more of the NFTs.
Should I create 50 different smart contracts or there is a special smart contract type that will come in handy?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a contract for NFTs is ERC-721. Within, you can create an arbitrary number of different NFTs. But in this case you want some NFTs to be 50plicated. In this case, you have two options:

1. You only need one artwork, and 50 copies of it. Use a token contract (ERC-20? ERC-777?).
2. You need one artwork, 50 copies of it, but you might want to add more artworks in the future (and perhaps, quantities of them). Use a multi-token contract (ERC-1155). This supports arbitrary tokens where you mint only 1 for NFTs, and you mint N or potentially infinite for fungible tokens.

Comment: about the 1st option, is it popular? such things can be traded in marketplaces?
which one of the options is more relevant for future trading purposes.

Comment: Not sure about the first option in thing like OpenSea.